# Do obstacle abilities work until the moment they are defeated?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The Trickster Initiate has the ability

> Obstacles ignore colorless damage applied to them

Does this mean if I play 3 colored and 3 colorless, could I then use the colored damage to finish killing him and then apply the colorless damage that very turn toward another obstacle?  Essentially, does the ability become nulled the moment he dies?

Answer (score 1):

From the way I read the [rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/CAT27700_Crossfire_Full%20Rules.pdf?86527a) you will be able to use colorless as in the apply damage step it lists defeating an enemy and it does not state you have to apply all damage before this. Also it should be noted that some defeat effects also will provide bonus damage which would also lead me to believe that you can do more damage after defeating an obstacle.

> Defeating an Obstacle
>   When you clear the last (far-right) level of an obstacle’s damage
>   track, you defeat it. If the obstacle has a defeated ability,
>   apply that effect.